# Passing Data to event handler in Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm developing a web app using Backbonejs.
I have a use case where I have to pass the new position of div1 to a double click event handler of a Backbone view.

My code looks like

```
var MyView = Backbone.Views.extend({
    events: {
    'dblclick #div1' : 'div1ClickHandler' //here I want to pass new offset for #div1
   }
});

div1ClickHandler: function()
{
......
}

var myView = new MyView({model: myModel,el : #div1});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by new position ? How do you calculate it ?

Comment: myView object is put under a jquery widget.After double click the widget size changes along with its offset. I'm taking its new position and dimensions.Please note that I dont have any control on widget.

Comment: So jquery widget is giving you the new dimensions and size.Right ?

Comment: My view is inside the jquery widget so yes jquery widget is giving me new dimensions

Comment: Doesn't below answers meet your expectation ?

Comment: Thanks for giving me valuable suggestions but I'm accepting something which is there in jQuery event callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your view element is a child element of the jquery widget, the best thing is probably to grab the values you need in the click handler:

```
var MyView = Backbone.Views.extend({
    events: {
    'dblclick #div1' : 'div1ClickHandler'
   }
});

div1ClickHandler: function()
{
  var $this = $(this);
  var $widget = $this.parents('.widget-selector:first');
  $this.offset($widget.offset());
  $this.height($widget.height());
  $this.width($widget.width());
}

var myView = new MyView({model: myModel,el : #div1});
```

If the jquery widget is always the direct parent of your view element, you can replace `parents('.widget-selector:first')` with `parent()`; otherwise, you'll need to replace `.widget-selector` with a selector that will work for the jquery widget.

Comment: Thanks, this surely will work.Infact I had tried this approch.But I wanted to know why data cannot be passed an parameter to handler function. Is there exist some design issues with it. If it is let me know.

Comment: Backbone does not support passing arbitrary data to the event handler. If the data were passed-in as a parameter, where would it be computed in the first-place?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that: inside `div` you need to add a new field with name `data-yourfieldName` and from js call that:

```
yourFunctionName: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $(e.currentTarget).data("yourfieldName");

}
```

Comment: No doubt, this is a good way to fetch data from DOM but in this case, we have to fetch data from jQuery widget. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass widget in view itself, then you will have full control over widget.

```
var MyView = Backbone.Views.extend({
initialize: function(options) {
    this.widget = options.widget; // You will get widget here which you passed at the time of view creation 
}

events: {
    'dblclick #div1' : 'div1ClickHandler' //here I want to pass new offset for #div1
   }
});

div1ClickHandler: function() {
 // Query to fetch new position and dimensions using widget
  // update the respective element

}

var myView = new MyView({model: myModel, el: $('#div1'), widget: widgetInstance});
```